# Force vim terminal to always show latest output

Tags: vim, terminal, vim-plugin

I am using a terminal inside vim (in a split window). I run my code there using [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime).

I love it, except for the fact that the terminal "falls behind": if I run 1000 lines of code, the terminal only shows the output of the first few. I have to manually scroll down (or change to the terminal window and press G) to go to the bottom of the outputs again.

Is there a way to force the terminal to behave as a normal (non-vim) terminal and simply keep up with the last outputs?